# Try Except for selenium webdriver or requests scripts

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, try-except

Thinking of best practices, is it good to use try except when trying to get respond from requests.get(url) or using selenium webdriver.get(url) ?

Maybe more general question, when its meant to be use try except - except of file handling?

Thank you.

for example:

```
import requests

try:
    respond = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
    print(respond.status_code)

except Exception as e:
    print(f'error while open url - {e}')
```

Comment: If you're only making a GET request through `requests` I don't think you need a `try except` block.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is good practice, even tough it might never come up especially when dealing with stable and widely used sites, such as Google-sites.

But in the case that the site you are trying to request is down or not responding to you, in my experience try except comes in handy and speeds up the process of finding the cause of an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is good practice to have, from experience if you leave the GET request outside of a try, if you wanted to loop through a list of URLs, this would end up falling over.

Also, if it fails, you could then handle that in the exception, for example your ip is blocked from accessing x website, you can output the url and either retry with proxies or write out the url for future handling.